# Why is the article "the" used with "population?"

Tags: grammar, descriptive-grammar

Why do we need an article before "population?"  Why is "the" the correct article to use in the following sentence?

> The population is suffering.

Comment: Example - "The population is suffering."

Comment: It refers to _the population of_ (the people living in) a particular country or region.

Answer (score 2):

*I recommend that you read [THIS](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/grammar/using_articles.html)  or [THIS](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/grammar/count_and_noncount_nouns/count_noncount_nouns_with_articles_adjectives.html#:%7E:text=Using%20Articles%20with%20Countable%20and,used%20in%20a%20general%20sense.) if you want to learn more about articles.*

There are three things that I will address in this answer: *which* articles we can use with "population," *when* to use each article, and *when* we need an article.

---

#### Which articles can be used with "population" and when should each one be used?

There are two types of articles: *definite* and *indefinite.*

**Definite** articles are used to refer to a *specific* noun.  The only definite article is **"the."**

For example:

> There is a child who is 5 years old.  **The child** goes to the store. [we are talking about a *specific* child]

**Indefinite** articles are used to refer to an unknown noun.  The two indefinite articles are **"a"** and **"an."**  "An" is used for nouns that begin with a *vowel sound* (e.g. apple, x-ray [pronounced "ex-ray"]).  "A" is used for words that begin with a *consonant sound* (e.g. book, laptop).

For example:

> I want to eat **an apple.** [not a specific apple, *any apple*]

OR

> I want to eat **a sandwich.** [not a specific sandwich, *any sandwhich*]

**Therefore, "population" would be accompanied by either "a" or "the," depending on its context.**

---

#### When is an article needed?

"Population" is a *countable noun*, which means that you can have one population, two populations, etc.  An uncountable noun would be something similar to "music" or "happiness."

Countable nouns **always require articles (either definite/"the" or indefinite/"a"/"an" when they are in their singular forms.**
For example:

> **The population** of China is growing rapidly.

OR

> Members of **a population** live in the same geographical location.

However, countable nouns **do not always require articles when plural;**  you only need to use an article to refer to a specific group.
For example:

> **Populations** are groups of people in the same area.

OR

> **The populations** described earlier [in a lecture or text] are rapidly growing.

Comment: Singular countable nouns can also be preceded by pronouns or adjectives. (*One population*, *another population*, *this population*, and so on.)

Comment: @JasonBassford That's a good point.  I just tried to focus on articles, but thanks for your addition.

Comment: [OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/population#:~:text=%5Bcountable%5D%20a%20particular%20group%20of,are%20disastrous%20for%20fish%20populations.) marks 'population' as having non-count usages also. I suspect this is true, but I can't think of any at the moment. // Ah, _population_ = _the process of populating (an area)_. 'The population/populating of these polar regions was very slow for 100 years.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You are right.  I found an example [here](https://www.wordreference.com/definition/population): "a definite decrease in population."  I didn't include this in my answer because the example sentence that the OP gave used in the countable sense.

Comment: This makes the use of '_population_ is a _count noun_' unsafe, unhelpful.